# Yum Updates Failed on CentOS 7 Due To mssql-tools/msodbcsql17 Conflict

Tags: centos7, yum

When I attempt to run yum updates on my CentOS 7 VM, the process aborts with the following information:

```
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
--> Running transaction check
---> Package kernel.x86_64 0:3.10.0-693.el7 will be erased
---> Package msodbcsql17.x86_64 0:17.2.0.1-1 will be updated
--> Processing Dependency: msodbcsql17 < 17.3.0.0 for package: mssql-tools-17.2.0.2-1.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: mssql-tools-17.2.0.2-1.x86_64 (@packages-microsoft-com-prod)
           Requires: msodbcsql17 < 17.3.0.0
           Removing: msodbcsql17-17.2.0.1-1.x86_64 (@packages-microsoft-com-prod)
               msodbcsql17 = 17.2.0.1-1
           Updated By: msodbcsql17-17.3.1.1-1.x86_64 (packages-microsoft-com-prod)
               msodbcsql17 = 17.3.1.1-1
           Available: msodbcsql17-17.0.1.1-1.x86_64 (packages-microsoft-com-prod)
               msodbcsql17 = 17.0.1.1-1
           Available: msodbcsql17-17.1.0.1-1.x86_64 (packages-microsoft-com-prod)
               msodbcsql17 = 17.1.0.1-1
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

How can I solve this properly without just skipping over the errors?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The repo is properly sync'd now. A normal install or update is possible again.

Answer (score 1):

Likely just a short term issue with the MS repos not in sync.
Periodically run:
    `yum clean all`
and try the update again.

Comment: I gave it a try, but unfortunately I'm still getting the same result.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by using a previous version

```
sudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y yum install msodbcsql17-17.2.0.1-1.x86_64 mssql-tools -y
```